# What is the domain and range of function: $f(x) = \arccos( -x^2 - \frac 12)$?

Tags: analysis

What is the domain and range of function: $f(x) = \arccos( -x^2 - \frac12)$ ?

**My attempt:**

We have $f(x)=\arccos(-x^2- 1/2)$, $g(x)= -x^2- 1/2$, $-1 \le -x^2 - 1/2 \le -1$ and $x^2 \ge 0$.

So $x^2 \le1/2$.

According that the domain of $g(x)$ is $Dg = [-1/√2 , 1/√2 ]$.

And the Range of $g(x)$ is $Rg = (-∞ , -1/2)$.

So the Range of g(x) will be our Domain of our function $f(x) ( f(x) = \arccos(g(x)))$ will be $Df = (-∞, -1/2)$.

In this case, the Range of our function $f(x)$ will be $Rf = (2π/3 , π)$.

Comment: By the restriction to $Dg = [-1/√2 , 1/√2 ]$ the range of g(x) is $Rg = (-1,-1/2)$ and then the range for f(x) is $Rf = (2π/3 , π)$ as you correctly stated. Therefore the only problem is with the range for $g(x)$ which you have indicated.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Recall that $\arccos (y)$ has domain $[-1,1]$ and range $[0,\pi]$.

What are domain and range for $g(x)=-x^2-\frac12$?

Comment: Domain for g(x) = [-1/(√2, 1/(√2)], and Range is all real numbers.

Comment: @SergeyVorobyev Recall that the domain for $g(x)$ is the set of all values where $g(x)$ is defined that is all $\mathbb{R}$ and the range is $(-\infty,-1/2]$. Can you see why?

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see it.

Comment: @SergeyVorobyev That's nice! Now you need to make a restriction for g(x) such that its range fits with the domain for $\arccos((g(x))$.

Comment: @SergeyVorobyev If you show your work editing your question, I'll take a look to it. Bye

Comment: Right know I understand. The Range for f(x) = arccos(-x^2 - 1/2) equals to (2π/3, π)

Comment: And Domain = (-1, -1/√2). Thank you for help!

Comment: @SergeyVorobyev Yes indeed since $-x^2-1/2 \le -1/2$ we need to restric $x$ such that $-x^2-1/2 \ge -1 \iff x^2 \le 1/2$

Comment: f(x)=arccos(-x^2- 1/2).  So g(x)= -x^2- 1/2.     -1 <= -x^2 - 1/2 <= -1 and x^2 >= 0. So x^2 <=1/2. According that the domain of g(x) is Dg = [-1/√2 , 1/√2 ]. And the Range of g(x) is Rg = (-∞ , -1/2). So the Range of g(x) will be our Domain of our function F(x) ( f(x) = arccos(g(x))) will be Df = (-∞, -1/2). In this case, the Range of our function f(x) will be  Rf = (2 π/3 , π). Right?! :-)

Comment: @SergeyVorobyev Yes exactly! Well done. It would be great is you put that derivation directly into you question as an editing. It would avoid downvoting and closure for your question.

Answer (score 0):

f(x)=arccos(-x^2- 1/2). g(x)= -x^2- 1/2. -1 <= -x^2 - 1/2 <= 1 and x^2 >= 0. So x^2 <=1/2. According that the domain of g(x) is Dg = [-1/√2 , 1/√2 ]. And the Range of g(x) is Rg = (-∞ , -1/2). So the Range of g(x) will be our Domain of our function f(x) ( f(x) = arccos(g(x))) will be Df = (-∞, -1/2). In this case, the Range of our function f(x) will beRf = (2π/3 , π).

Comment: Let add your derivation directly in your original question by editing it.

Comment: I don't know any about it yet, sorry. :-)

Comment: Try to follow the suggestion given as a comment under your OP. Try to revise that accordinlgy. You can delete that answer.